Table with resizebox not fitting all the data into my page, however I dont know how to use longtable to generate table on multiple pages
Below is the Code for the table, it has a total of 81 rows. However, it is currently printing only 62 rows.
%%%
% *** TABLE PACKAGES ***
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{boldline} 
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
 \usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
 \usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % For row colors

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3} % Adjust row height
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm} % Thicker lines for section separations
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt} % Adjust column spacing

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % Adjust text wrapping
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % Left-aligned column
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}   % Center-aligned column
\newcolumntype{X}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}} % Wrappable column
\usepackage{adjustbox} % Add this to your preamble
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{table}[]

\caption{ List of simulations performed for the input design space and their corresponding output response variables.}
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllllllllll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Run}                     & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Factor 1 \\ A:Du\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Factor 2 \\ B:DO\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Factor 3 \\ C:a\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Factor 4 \\ D:b\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Factor 5 \\ E:S\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Factor 6 \\ F:h\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Factor 7 \\ G:ch\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Factor 8 \\ H:V\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Factor 9 \\ J:Design\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Response 1 \\ Cutsize (microns)\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Response 2 \\ Sharpness\end{tabular}} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{1}}  & 0.2                                                               & 0.25                                                              & 0.2                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 1                                                                & 0.5                                                              & 2.5                                                               & 4                                                                & Concave                                                               & 4.8                                                                              & 0.8019                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{2}}  & 0.2                                                               & 0.75                                                              & 0.2                                                              & 0.2                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 0.5                                                              & 2.5                                                               & 16                                                               & Concave                                                               & 3.8                                                                              & 0.7771                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{3}}  & 0.6                                                               & 0.75                                                              & 0.7                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 1                                                                & 1.5                                                              & 1.5                                                               & 4                                                                & Convex                                                                & 8                                                                                & 0.4231                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{4}}  & 0.2                                                               & 0.75                                                              & 0.7                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 1                                                                & 2.5                                                               & 4                                                                & Convex                                                                & 12.5                                                                             & 0.2500                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{5}}  & 0.3                                                               & 0.375                                                             & 0.575                                                            & 0.15                                                             & 0.475                                                            & 0.75                                                             & 1                                                                 & 13                                                               & Concave                                                               & 1.93                                                                             & 0.7072                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{6}}  & 0.2                                                               & 0.25                                                              & 0.7                                                              & 0.1                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 1.5                                                              & 2.5                                                               & 4                                                                & Convex                                                                & 5.8                                                                              & 0.7536                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{7}}  & 0.2                                                               & 0.75                                                              & 0.45                                                             & 0.1                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 0.5                                                              & 0.5                                                               & 4                                                                & Concave                                                               & 8.5                                                                              & 0.6075                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{8}}  & 0.6                                                               & 0.25                                                              & 0.2                                                              & 0.1                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 1.5                                                              & 0.5                                                               & 4                                                                & Standard                                                              & 8.1                                                                              & 0.5044                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{9}}  & 0.2                                                               & 0.25                                                              & 0.7                                                              & 0.1                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 1.5                                                              & 2.5                                                               & 4                                                                & Standard                                                              & 5.65                                                                             & 0.7813                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{10}} & 0.6                                                               & 0.25                                                              & 0.7                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 1.5                                                              & 2.5                                                               & 4                                                                & Convex                                                                & 5.1                                                                              & 0.7826                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{11}} & 0.2                                                               & 0.5                                                               & 0.7                                                              & 0.1                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 1.5                                                              & 2.5                                                               & 16                                                               & Convex                                                                & 2.3                                                                              & 0.7170                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{12}} & 0.3                                                               & 0.375                                                             & 0.575                                                            & 0.25                                                             & 0.825                                                            & 1.25                                                             & 1                                                                 & 13                                                               & Concave                                                               & 1.87                                                                             & 0.6828                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{18}} & 0.4                                                               & 0.625                                                             & 0.325                                                            & 0.25                                                             & 0.825                                                            & 1.25                                                             & 2                                                                 & 7                                                                & Standard                                                              & 4.9                                                                              & 0.8077                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{19}} & 0.6                                                               & 0.25                                                              & 0.7                                                              & 0.2                                                              & 1                                                                & 0.5                                                              & 2.5                                                               & 4                                                                & Concave                                                               & 5.05                                                                             & 0.8036                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{20}} & 0.6                                                               & 0.5                                                               & 0.7                                                              & 0.1                                                              & 1                                                                & 1.5                                                              & 0.5                                                               & 4                                                                & Convex                                                                & 6.75                                                                             & 0.7097                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{21}} & 0.2                                                               & 0.25                                                              & 0.7                                                              & 0.1                                                              & 1                                                                & 1.5                                                              & 1.5                                                               & 4                                                                & Convex                                                                & 6.15                                                                             & 0.7103                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{22}} & 0.2                                                               & 0.75                                                              & 0.2                                                              & 0.1                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 1.5                                                              & 0.5                                                               & 4                                                                & Concave                                                               & 12                                                                               & 0.5167                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{23}} & 0.3                                                               & 0.625                                                             & 0.325                                                            & 0.15                                                             & 0.475                                                            & 0.75                                                             & 2                                                                 & 7                                                                & Concave                                                               & 4.6                                                                              & 0.7379                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{24}} & 0.3                                                               & 0.625                                                             & 0.325                                                            & 0.25                                                             & 0.475                                                            & 1.25                                                             & 1                                                                 & 13                                                               & Concave                                                               & 2.05                                                                             & 0.7390                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{25}} & 0.3                                                               & 0.625                                                             & 0.575                                                            & 0.25                                                             & 0.825                                                            & 1                                                                & 1                                                                 & 13                                                               & Standard                                                              & 3.3                                                                              & 0.5926                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{26}} & 0.4                                                               & 0.75                                                              & 0.2                                                              & 0.1                                                              & 1                                                                & 1.5                                                              & 2.5                                                               & 16                                                               & Standard                                                              & 5.3                                                                              & 0.7627                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{27}} & 0.5                                                               & 0.375                                                             & 0.325                                                            & 0.25                                                             & 0.65                                                             & 0.75                                                             & 1                                                                 & 13                                                               & Concave                                                               & 2                                                                                & 0.7623                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{74}} & 0.6                                                               & 0.75                                                              & 0.7                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 0.5                                                              & 2.5                                                               & 4                                                                & Standard                                                              & 9                                                                                & 0.2778                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{75}} & 0.5                                                               & 0.625                                                             & 0.575                                                            & 0.15                                                             & 0.825                                                            & 1                                                                & 2                                                                 & 13                                                               & Convex                                                                & 2.15                                                                             & 0.7292                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{76}} & 0.4                                                               & 0.5                                                               & 0.45                                                             & 0.2                                                              & 0.65                                                             & 1                                                                & 1                                                                 & 10                                                               & Standard                                                              & 2.75                                                                             & 0.8000                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{77}} & 0.3                                                               & 0.375                                                             & 0.575                                                            & 0.2                                                              & 0.825                                                            & 0.75                                                             & 1                                                                 & 13                                                               & Standard                                                              & 2.68                                                                             & 0.7516                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{78}} & 0.2                                                               & 0.75                                                              & 0.7                                                              & 0.1                                                              & 0.65                                                             & 1.5                                                              & 0.5                                                               & 4                                                                & Concave                                                               & 8.1                                                                              & 0.7135                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{79}} & 0.3                                                               & 0.5                                                               & 0.575                                                            & 0.25                                                             & 0.825                                                            & 0.75                                                             & 1                                                                 & 13                                                               & Standard                                                              & 2.8                                                                              & 0.6973                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{80}} & 0.3                                                               & 0.5                                                               & 0.575                                                            & 0.15                                                             & 0.825                                                            & 1.25                                                             & 2                                                                 & 7                                                                & Concave                                                               & 4.1                                                                              & 0.5893                                                                   \\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{81}}& 0.4                                                               & 0.25                                                              & 0.2                                                              & 0.3                                                              & 1                                                                & 0.5                                                              & 0.5                                                               & 16                                                               & Concave                                                               & 1.52                                                                             & 0.7143                                                                   \\ \bottomrule
\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\end{table}


Never scale elements which contain text and stay away from the awful online table generators - they make it unnecessarily hard to get a good looking table.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Can you clarify if you want to break the table across multiple pages or if you want to have it on one page?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Thank you for your reply. I want it across 2 pages, maximum

Please tell us which document class you employ.

Make a small complete document which shows the problem, but never scale tables with \resizebox or adjustbox etc. Certainly if you want a page break then that is not possible at all.

table, tabular and \resizebox all make a box that can not break over a page, so you need to not use any of those, see longtable or similar packages for multi-page tables.

@Mico: \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report} for thesis.

@user3454353 - Thanks for this piece of information. Please also state how wide the textblock is. Alternatively, how wide are the margins?

Could you adjust your title?  "I don't to use" isn't grammatical.  Should it be "I don't know how to use"?  Or "I don't want to use"?

Since your table needs to span at least two pages, I suggest you switch from a table/tabular setup (which doesn't allow page breaks) to a longtable setup. To save on horizontal space and thus avoid having to resort to the \resizebox sledgehammer, I further suggest that you (a) remove redundancies in the header rows, (b) let LaTeX figure out the available intercolumn whitespace amounts, and (c) omit all bold-facing in the header rows and the first column as it takes up a lot of space and isn't needed -- at least not in a well-designed table. In addition, you may want to align the numbers in the data columns on their (explicit or implicit) decimal markers in order to make the numerical information easier to read and absorb.
See the code below for ways to implement these ideas.

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report} % per the OP's comment
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page margins as needed 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
% Handy shortcut macro:
\newcommand\mytab[1]{{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\usepackage{siunitx} % For '\unit' macro and 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % Limit scope of next 4 instructions to current group
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} % see section 6 of user guide of 'longtable' package
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out intercolumn whitespace

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
   l
   T{1.1}
   T{1.3}
   T{1.3}
   T{1.2}
   T{1.3}
   T{1.2}
   T{1.1}
   T{2.0}
   l
   T{2.2}
   T{1.4}}

% headers and footers

\caption{List of simulations performed for the input design 
space and their corresponding output response variables.}\\
\toprule
Run & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Factors} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Responses}\\
\cmidrule{2-10} \cmidrule{11-12}
& \mytab{1 \\ A:Du} & \mytab{2 \\ B:DO} & \mytab{3 \\ C:a}  & 
  \mytab{4 \\ D:b}  & \mytab{5 \\ E:S}  & \mytab{6 \\ F:h}  & 
  \mytab{7 \\ G:ch} & \mytab{8 \\ H:V}  & \mytab{9 \\ J:Design} & 
  \mytab{1 \\ Cutsize (\unit{\micro\meter})} & \mytab{2 \\ Sharpness} \\   
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{12}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\toprule
Run & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Factors} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Responses}\\
\cmidrule{2-10} \cmidrule{11-12}
& \mytab{1 \\ A:Du} & \mytab{2 \\ B:DO} & \mytab{3 \\ C:a}  & 
  \mytab{4 \\ D:b}  & \mytab{5 \\ E:S}  & \mytab{6 \\ F:h}  & 
  \mytab{7 \\ G:ch} & \mytab{8 \\ H:V}  & \mytab{9 \\ J:Design} & 
  \mytab{1 \\ Cutsize (\unit{\micro\meter})} & \mytab{2 \\ Sharpness} \\  
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{12}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

% body of table

1  & 0.2  & 0.25 & 0.2  & 0.3  & 1    & 0.5  & 2.5  & 4   & Concave  & 4.8  & 0.8019 \\
2  & 0.2  & 0.75 & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.3  & 0.5  & 2.5  & 16  & Concave  & 3.8  & 0.7771 \\
3  & 0.6  & 0.75 & 0.7  & 0.3  & 1    & 1.5  & 1.5  & 4   & Convex   & 8    & 0.4231 \\
4  & 0.2  & 0.75 & 0.7  & 0.3  & 0.3  & 1    & 2.5  & 4   & Convex   & 12.5 & 0.2500 \\
5  & 0.3  & 0.375& 0.575& 0.15 & 0.475& 0.75 &      & 13  & Concave  & 1.93 & 0.7072 \\
6  & 0.2  & 0.25 & 0.7  & 0.1  & 0.3  & 1.5  & 2.5  & 4   & Convex   & 5.8  & 0.7536 \\
7  & 0.2  & 0.75 & 0.45 & 0.1  & 0.3  & 0.5  & 0.5  & 4   & Concave  & 8.5  & 0.6075 \\
8  & 0.6  & 0.25 & 0.2  & 0.1  & 0.3  & 1.5  & 0.5  & 4   & Standard & 8.1  & 0.5044 \\
9  & 0.2  & 0.25 & 0.7  & 0.1  & 0.3  & 1.5  & 2.5  & 4   & Standard & 5.65 & 0.7813 \\
10 & 0.6  & 0.25 & 0.7  & 0.3  & 0.3  & 1.5  & 2.5  & 4   & Convex   & 5.1  & 0.7826 \\
11 & 0.2  & 0.5  & 0.7  & 0.1  & 0.3  & 1.5  & 2.5  & 16  & Convex   & 2.3  & 0.7170 \\
12 & 0.3  & 0.375& 0.575& 0.25 & 0.825& 1.25 &      & 13  & Concave  & 1.87 & 0.6828 \\
18 & 0.4  & 0.625& 0.325& 0.25 & 0.825& 1.25 & 2    & 7   & Standard & 4.9  & 0.8077 \\
19 & 0.6  & 0.25 & 0.7  & 0.2  & 1    & 0.5  & 2.5  & 4   & Concave  & 5.05 & 0.8036 \\
20 & 0.6  & 0.5  & 0.7  & 0.1  & 1    & 1.5  & 0.5  & 4   & Convex   & 6.75 & 0.7097 \\
21 & 0.2  & 0.25 & 0.7  & 0.1  & 1    & 1.5  & 1.5  & 4   & Convex   & 6.15 & 0.7103 \\
22 & 0.2  & 0.75 & 0.2  & 0.1  & 0.3  & 1.5  & 0.5  & 4   & Concave  & 12   & 0.5167 \\
23 & 0.3  & 0.625& 0.325& 0.15 & 0.475& 0.75 & 2    & 7   & Concave  & 4.6  & 0.7379 \\
24 & 0.3  & 0.625& 0.325& 0.25 & 0.475& 1.25 &      & 13  & Concave  & 2.05 & 0.7390 \\
25 & 0.3  & 0.625& 0.575& 0.25 & 0.825& 1    &      & 13  & Standard & 3.3  & 0.5926 \\
26 & 0.4  & 0.75 & 0.2  & 0.1  & 1    & 1.5  & 2.5  & 16  & Standard & 5.3  & 0.7627 \\
27 & 0.5  & 0.375& 0.325& 0.25 & 0.65 & 0.75 &      & 13  & Concave  & 2    & 0.7623 \\
\addlinespace
74 & 0.6  & 0.75 & 0.7  & 0.3  & 0.3  & 0.5  & 2.5  & 4   & Standard & 9    & 0.2778 \\
75 & 0.5  & 0.625& 0.575& 0.15 & 0.825& 1    & 2    & 13  & Convex   & 2.15 & 0.7292 \\
76 & 0.4  & 0.5  & 0.45 & 0.2  & 0.65 & 1    &      & 10  & Standard & 2.75 & 0.8000 \\
77 & 0.3  & 0.375& 0.575& 0.2  & 0.825& 0.75 &      & 13  & Standard & 2.68 & 0.7516 \\
78 & 0.2  & 0.75 & 0.7  & 0.1  & 0.65 & 1.5  & 0.5  & 4   & Concave  & 8.1  & 0.7135 \\
79 & 0.3  & 0.5  & 0.575& 0.25 & 0.825& 0.75 &      & 13  & Standard & 2.8  & 0.6973 \\
80 & 0.3  & 0.5  & 0.575& 0.15 & 0.825& 1.25 & 2    & 7   & Concave  & 4.1  & 0.5893 \\
81 & 0.4  & 0.25 & 0.2  & 0.3  & 1    & 0.5  & 0.5  & 16  & Concave  & 1.52 & 0.7143 \\

\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}


Thank you so much Mico

An alternative approach do formatting your table. By use of the longtblr of tabularray package, code is quite shorter and simpler, however this is payed with a bit longer compilation time.
For using caption package for caption formatting is added package tablr-extras, for simpler reading of table, rows are grouped: after four rows is inserted  additional vertical space.
MWE below is based on nice @Mico answer (+1):
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report} % per the OP's comment
\usepackage[hmargin=25mm]{geometry} % set page margins as needed
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont=bf,
            skip=0.25\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tblr-extras}    % <--- new
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                caption,
                siunitx}    % <--- new
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{\footnotesize\itshape}
\NewColumnType{T}[1]{X[si={table-format=#1},c]}
\NewColumnType{U}[1]{Q[si={table-format=#1},c]}
\ExplSyntaxOn               % <--- new
\NewChildSelector{eachfour}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {2}{4}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {List of simulations performed for the input design 
           space and their corresponding output response variables.},
  label = {longtab:1}
                        ]{colsep  = 3pt,
                          colspec = {@{}
                                     l T{1.1} T{1.3} T{1.3} T{1.2}
                                       T{1.3} T{1.2} T{1.1} T{2.0}
                                     l U{2.2} U{1.4}
                                     @{}},
                          row{1,2} = {guard, c},
                          rowsep   = 0pt,
                          row{eachfour} = {belowsep=1.5ex},
                          rowhead  = 1
                          }
% headers 
    \toprule
Run &   \SetCell[c=9]{c}    Factors 
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Responses
                                            &   \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-10} \cmidrule[l]{11-12}
    &{1 \\ A:Du} &{2 \\ B:DO} &{3 \\ C:a}  
    &{4 \\ D:b}  &{5 \\ E:S}  &{6 \\ F:h}  
    &{7 \\ G:ch} &{8 \\ H:V}  &{9 \\ J:Design} 
    &{1 \\ Cutsize (\unit{\micro\meter})} 
                 &{2 \\ Sharpness}  \\
    \midrule
% body of table
1  & 0.2  & 0.25 & 0.2  & 0.3  & 1    & 0.5  & 2.5  & 4   & Concave  & 4.8  & 0.8019 \\
2  & 0.2  & 0.75 & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.3  & 0.5  & 2.5  & 16  & Concave  & 3.8  & 0.7771 \\
3  & 0.6  & 0.75 & 0.7  & 0.3  & 1    & 1.5  & 1.5  & 4   & Convex   & 8    & 0.4231 \\
4  & 0.2  & 0.75 & 0.7  & 0.3  & 0.3  & 1    & 2.5  & 4   & Convex   & 12.5 & 0.2500 \\
5  & 0.3  & 0.375& 0.575& 0.15 & 0.475& 0.75 &      & 13  & Concave  & 1.93 & 0.7072 \\
6  & 0.2  & 0.25 & 0.7  & 0.1  & 0.3  & 1.5  & 2.5  & 4   & Convex   & 5.8  & 0.7536 \\
7  & 0.2  & 0.75 & 0.45 & 0.1  & 0.3  & 0.5  & 0.5  & 4   & Concave  & 8.5  & 0.6075 \\
8  & 0.6  & 0.25 & 0.2  & 0.1  & 0.3  & 1.5  & 0.5  & 4   & Standard & 8.1  & 0.5044 \\
9  & 0.2  & 0.25 & 0.7  & 0.1  & 0.3  & 1.5  & 2.5  & 4   & Standard & 5.65 & 0.7813 \\
10 & 0.6  & 0.25 & 0.7  & 0.3  & 0.3  & 1.5  & 2.5  & 4   & Convex   & 5.1  & 0.7826 \\
11 & 0.2  & 0.5  & 0.7  & 0.1  & 0.3  & 1.5  & 2.5  & 16  & Convex   & 2.3  & 0.7170 \\
12 & 0.3  & 0.375& 0.575& 0.25 & 0.825& 1.25 &      & 13  & Concave  & 1.87 & 0.6828 \\
18 & 0.4  & 0.625& 0.325& 0.25 & 0.825& 1.25 & 2    & 7   & Standard & 4.9  & 0.8077 \\
19 & 0.6  & 0.25 & 0.7  & 0.2  & 1    & 0.5  & 2.5  & 4   & Concave  & 5.05 & 0.8036 \\
20 & 0.6  & 0.5  & 0.7  & 0.1  & 1    & 1.5  & 0.5  & 4   & Convex   & 6.75 & 0.7097 \\
21 & 0.2  & 0.25 & 0.7  & 0.1  & 1    & 1.5  & 1.5  & 4   & Convex   & 6.15 & 0.7103 \\
22 & 0.2  & 0.75 & 0.2  & 0.1  & 0.3  & 1.5  & 0.5  & 4   & Concave  & 12   & 0.5167 \\
23 & 0.3  & 0.625& 0.325& 0.15 & 0.475& 0.75 & 2    & 7   & Concave  & 4.6  & 0.7379 \\
24 & 0.3  & 0.625& 0.325& 0.25 & 0.475& 1.25 &      & 13  & Concave  & 2.05 & 0.7390 \\
25 & 0.3  & 0.625& 0.575& 0.25 & 0.825& 1    &      & 13  & Standard & 3.3  & 0.5926 \\
26 & 0.4  & 0.75 & 0.2  & 0.1  & 1    & 1.5  & 2.5  & 16  & Standard & 5.3  & 0.7627 \\
27 & 0.5  & 0.375& 0.325& 0.25 & 0.65 & 0.75 &      & 13  & Concave  & 2    & 0.7623 \\

74 & 0.6  & 0.75 & 0.7  & 0.3  & 0.3  & 0.5  & 2.5  & 4   & Standard & 9    & 0.2778 \\
75 & 0.5  & 0.625& 0.575& 0.15 & 0.825& 1    & 2    & 13  & Convex   & 2.15 & 0.7292 \\
76 & 0.4  & 0.5  & 0.45 & 0.2  & 0.65 & 1    &      & 10  & Standard & 2.75 & 0.8000 \\
77 & 0.3  & 0.375& 0.575& 0.2  & 0.825& 0.75 &      & 13  & Standard & 2.68 & 0.7516 \\
78 & 0.2  & 0.75 & 0.7  & 0.1  & 0.65 & 1.5  & 0.5  & 4   & Concave  & 8.1  & 0.7135 \\
79 & 0.3  & 0.5  & 0.575& 0.25 & 0.825& 0.75 &      & 13  & Standard & 2.8  & 0.6973 \\
80 & 0.3  & 0.5  & 0.575& 0.15 & 0.825& 1.25 & 2    & 7   & Concave  & 4.1  & 0.5893 \\
81 & 0.4  & 0.25 & 0.2  & 0.3  & 1    & 0.5  & 0.5  & 16  & Concave  & 1.52 & 0.7143 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}


